# ICU Package installation Linux

Tags: c#, linux, icu

When I try to run a c# program on my linux controller I get the following error:

```
    Process terminated. Couldn't find a valid ICU package installed on the system. Set the configuration flag System.Globalization.Invariant to true if you want to run with no globalization support.
   at System.Environment.FailFast(System.String)
   at System.Globalization.GlobalizationMode.GetGlobalizationInvariantMode()
   at System.Globalization.GlobalizationMode..cctor()
   at System.Globalization.CultureData.CreateCultureWithInvariantData()
   at System.Globalization.CultureData.get_Invariant()
   at System.Globalization.CultureInfo..cctor()
   at System.StringComparer..cctor()
   at System.StringComparer.get_OrdinalIgnoreCase()
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnectionStringBuilder..cctor()
```

I want to install an ICU package to get rid of this error. So I downloaded a package from this site:
[Internationnal Components for Unicode](http://site.icu-project.org/home)

When I installed the package on the controller I still got the message. Is there any proper way to install an ICU package on the linux controller so I can get rid of this message?

P.S. (turning globalization invariant on is not an option because my code (SQL-Server) does not allow it to be on...)

Comment: Which version of dotnet are you running, and where did you get it from? If it's from your Linux distro, can you try installing the libicu package from your distro too? If it was from Microsoft directly, are there release notes telling you which version of libicu it was built against, i.e. which one it expects to find?

Comment: @Rup Currently I am using visual code to build my c# program to linux and in to a binary file. I build it in to a NetCore app version 3.0. Then on the Linux controller I use the command: chmod +x "filename" to make it executible on linux. The controller doesn't have the capabilitiy to use apt-get or any of these commands. I can download debian packages and install those. So to sum it up. I don't use Dotnet on linux, I use visual code for that.

Comment: OK. I'd try using 1) ldd on your executable to see if it has a dependency on libicu (but I'd guess it won't); 2) strace on the executable and look for an attempt to dlopen libicu there, to see what file it's looking for and where, or if there are any errors attempting to use the .so you've built yourself.

Comment: @Rup, So if I understand correctly I don't need to install ICU package on the linux controller, but I can download the library and integrate it in my code? I will try this as soon as possible.

Comment: No, I'd guess the executable is trying to load it dynamically so you will need it on your controller I'd think. I was suggesting ways to debug it failing to load libicu so you can work out how to correct that.

Comment: @Rup, I think the problem is that I don't have libicu installed on the controller, but I don't have the possibility to install it with apt-get, do you have any idea how to install it?

Answer (score 6):

you can disable ICU usage putting this in your .csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <InvariantGlobalization>true</InvariantGlobalization>
</PropertyGroup>
```

before running your project, delete manually /bin and /obj

Comment: Don't need to manually delete /bin and /obj.  Simply adding the property works.